# PERL program to mimic cat utility

Tags: perl

In the below mentioned program,can somebody explain the expression used in the while loop

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub print_file {
    my $file = shift;
    open FILE, $file;
    while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
        print $line;
    }
}

sub cat {
    while ( my $file = shift ) {
        print_file $file;
    }
}

cat @ARGV;
```

Comment: That's a long-winded way of writing `while (<>) { print; }`, isn't it?

Comment: shortest cat emulation is `perl -pe1 filenames....`, check `perlrun`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not clear which while loop is confusing you.

`my $file = shift` removes the first remaining element from `@_` (which contains the parameters passed to sub cat) and assigns it to $file.  The while loop exits if this was false (which it will be when there are no more elements in `@_` or if you have a file named `0` or an empty argument to the script).

`my $line = <FILE>` uses the readline operator (sometimes `<>` is readline, sometimes it is glob, depends what is in the brackets) to read a line from the given filehandle and assigns it to $line.  As a special case, using this form of while test gets an implicit defined test added, so it is treated as if you said `while ( defined( my $line = <FILE> ) )`, so the while loop only terminates on undef (indicating no more lines in the file or some other IO error), not on a line that happens to be false (e.g. a `0` at the end of a file with no newline following it).

Note that this script does a poor job emulating cat; as mentioned, it will fail if a file is named `0`, but it will also have trouble with files with leading or trailing whitespace in their names or several other cases (such as names beginning with '<' or '>').

Comment: @mpapec: not best practice, but not at all an issue in a script.  in reusable code, yes, that would be a major issue.